# Is World XI a full member of ICC

Tags: cricket, statistics, icc

Is World XI team a full member of ICC like Australia, South Africa? Is its match considered international or domestic? Would the wickets,catches,runs etc scored by a player in World XI team be included in its international career or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ICC members are made up of *governing bodies*, not *teams*. Therefore the World XI, which was a team directly organised by the ICC, **is not an ICC member** itself.

However, the matches [were given ODI and Test status](http://www.espncricinfo.com/magazine/content/story/288887.html). They therefore **do count towards official international records**, and individual player statistics.